# How can I tell my roommates I don't want to live with them anymore

Tags: friends, roommates

I currently live with 3 roommates. Two of them joined last year and the other one has lived with me for 4 years. The problem is that I don't feel really comfortable living with them anymore and I want to move out. It's really difficult to me to tell them what's going on because I am very shy and they are not my friends at all. Well, the one who lived with me for 4 years is actually my friend but the relationship is not as good as it was because of the new roommates. How should I tell them that I want to move out?

Comment: Some extra information as to your relationship with each of them, and your reasons for wanting to move would be very beneficial to potential answers

Comment: I agree with Jesse, and also, some questions -`1)` if you could, you would want to move out with this one friend? `1)` The problem is mainly the two new roommates? `3)` What's holding you from just tell them you decided to look for another place - afraid of their comment? their feelings? `4)` That maybe it will affect you in the future?  `5)` Do you with to keep good contact (friendly, friendly+) with at least the friend, or it's important regards all of them?

Answer (score 9):

If you've decided on doing this, then I'd suggest starting from a position of facts and not emotion.  Anyone who has had a roommate knows that the relationship is not permanent - roommates come and go.  It's part of life with roommates.

They need time to find a new roommate, so the sooner the better.  Set the date when you plan on moving out by, and have that discussion.  "Guys, I'm going to move out on [x date].  I want to let you know in advance so you've got time to find a replacement if you want to."  If they want to know why (and generally they won't), tell them the truth: "I feel like a change/I want my own place/I feel like doing something different".  There's no need to go into too much detail here.  That explanation will generally do.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (several years of leaving with other students in different houses), people moving out isn't really a big deal. Just explain several weeks beforehand (so paperwork can be taken care of) that you're doing so. A simple reason like

> I would like some more room for myself

Is both true and doesn't pressure people into feeling attacked. It also allows people to do something nice for you when you leave.

I have noticed people appreciate some sort of moment to say goodbye. A simple dinner at home or a couple drinks allow this. It is always better not to burn your bridges if possible.